# Mine Tweets between two dates in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I would like to mine tweets for two keywords for a specific period of time. I currently have the code below, but how do I add so it only mine tweets between two dates? (10/03/2016 - 10/07/2016) Thank you!

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY"
consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    #This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
    stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

Comment: @Efferalgan why is that a comment and not an answer? it feels bad to answer this question when the answer has already been given! :|

Comment: @Loïc I get a "trivial answert converted to a comment", and I feel bad posting such a trivial answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205102/making-very-specific-time-requests-to-the-second-on-twitter-api-using-python), that is the closest you can get.

The Twitter API does not allow to search by time. Trivially, what you can do is fetching tweets and looking at their timestamps afterwards in Python, but that is highly inefficient.

Comment: ah, i see. I should have been clear. I can fetch tweets by date though? I'm not looking at specific times. I'm mostly wishing to mine tweets between two dates.

Comment: Nope. There is no way to search tweets by time, or date. As the answer to the question I linked reads, there is the `since_id` option that will only return tweets posted later than the one you provided, but sadly that's about your only option here.

Comment: Well, none of my messages really were of any help, sadly.