# Working with datetime in order to run script every 15 minutes

Tags: python, datetime, tweepy

I am making a twitter bot that is returning way to much Tweets every time. So I chose to make a script that just runs every 15 minutes and takes all the tweets from the last 15 minutes. I am trying to use the datetime package in combination with the tweepy package. This is unfortunately not working. I am trying to set the since and until variables of the Tweepy cursor correctly. Anyone seeing something wrong with my code?

```
while True:
    query = ['word']
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    previous = datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    difference = now-previous
    print (now, previous, difference)
    con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='...' user='...' password='...'")   
    cur = con.cursor()
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, since=difference, until=now, count=1000).items(10) :
        print(tweet.created_at)
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO .......(created_at, tweet_id, tweet, reply_to_user_id, reply_to_screen_name, user_id, user_name, followers_count, retweet_count)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
        (tweet.created_at,
         tweet.id,
         tweet.text,
         tweet.in_reply_to_user_id,
         tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name,
         tweet.user.id,
         tweet.user.name,
         tweet.user.followers_count,
         tweet.retweet_count))
    con.commit()
    time.sleep(900)
```

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205102/making-very-specific-time-requests-to-the-second-on-twitter-api-using-python)? Might be outdated though.

Comment: This is likely better done with the `cron` facility of your OS: running your script every 15 minutes is just the sort of thing the OS does; no need to write it yourself.