# How to save all replies and comments of a twitter username within specific time period?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am going to collect all the comments of a particular Twitter username within 2018. How can I do that?

The code below scrape tweets for one tweet without time consideration:

```
name = 'MoveTheWorld'
tweet_id = '1310127204538482690'
replies=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='to:'+name, result_type='recent', timeout=999999).items(8000):
if hasattr(tweet, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
    if (tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str==tweet_id):                        
        replies.append(tweet)
```

Comment: Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731259/tweepy-get-tweets-between-two-dates) it might help.

Comment: @RedSalas the query returns the same result even if you change the dates. It sound it collects the most recent tweets on that page.