# Why do I receive the error message when downloading a user timeline using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, textblob, twitterapi-python

I am working on my thesis for economics and I am trying to scrape tweets between two dates for a list of users. Unfortunately, my program, which works fine for a single user breaks and throws this error when I try to loop it for the followers of an influencer. Anyone have suggestions?

Also once I get that fixed I will need to sort between two dates (I was just going to download a massive amount and then sort later using SPSS, but there must be a better way). Does anyone know a way to do this I tried this: [tweepy get tweets between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731259/tweepy-get-tweets-between-two-dates)
but it didn't work and gave me super irregular results. Also if anyone knows how to make this not trip rate limits that would be great because I think that will be the next problem. :)

Sorry if the code is a little messy it is my first time coding.

**The error (I am working in spyder so its a bit long):**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\XPS.ipython\OG + BUILD UP FROM SCRACH.py", line 91, in 
extract_followers(user)

File "C:\Users\XPS.ipython\OG + BUILD UP FROM SCRACH.py", line 66, in extract_followers
posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name = user, count = 100, language = "en", tweet_mode="extended", include_rts = True)

File "C:\Users\XPS\Python\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 252, in _call
return method.execute()

File "C:\Users\XPS\Python\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 238, in execute
result = self.parser.parse(self, resp.text, return_cursors=self.return_cursors)

File "C:\Users\XPS\Python\lib\site-packages\tweepy\parsers.py", line 98, in parse
result = model.parse_list(method.api, json)

File "C:\Users\XPS\Python\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py", line 75, in parse_list
results.append(cls.parse(api, obj))

**File "C:\Users\XPS\Python\lib\site-packages\tweepy\models.py", line 89, in parse
**for k, v in json.items():**
**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'****

**My Code**

## Import the libraries

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob 
import pandas as pd
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

## Twitter API Credentials

```
consumerkey =  ('a')
consumersecret = ('a')
bearer = ('a')
token = ('a')
tokensecret = ('a')
```

## Create the authentication object

```
authenticate = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerkey, consumersecret)
```

#Set the access token

```
authenticate.set_access_token(token, tokensecret)
```

#create the API object while passing in the auth info

```
api = tweepy.API(authenticate, wait_on_rate_limit= True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

## Create a function to clean the tweets

```
def cleanTxt(text):
 text = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0–9]+', '', text) #Removing @mentions
 text = re.sub('#', '', text) # Removing '#' hash tag
 text = re.sub('RT[\s]+', '', text) # Removing RT
 text = re.sub('https?:\/\/\S+', '', text) # Removing hyperlink
 text = re.sub('https?:\/\/\S+', '', text) # Removing hyperlink

 return text
```

## Create a function to get the subjectivity

```
def getSubjectivity(text):
   return TextBlob(text).sentiment.subjectivity
```

## Create a function to get the polarity (how positive or negative the txt is)

```
def getPolarity(text):
   return  TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity
```

#list of followers

```
name_list = ['_prashantnair','urxnlc', 'Gurmeet1018', 'arpit8691yahooc', 'bnirmaljain', 'anoldschoolboy', 'rrpatange']
```

In some versions I just call an excel - The full list is a few thousand per influencer

## Create function to extract 100 tweets from the influencer with dates

```
def extract_followers (user):
    results = []
    posts = api.user_timeline(screen_name = user, count = 100, language = "en", tweet_mode="extended", include_rts = True)
    for tweet in posts:
            data = (
            tweet.full_text,
            tweet.created_at,
            tweet.user.screen_name)
            results.append(data)
        
        
    cols = "Tweets Date screen_name".split()
    global df
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=cols)
    
    print("df original")
    print (df)
    
    for tweet in posts:
            cleaned_text = cleanTxt(tweet.full_text)
            with open('influencer.csv', 'a', newline= '') as f:    
                worksheet = csv.writer(f)
                worksheet.writerow([str(tweet.user.screen_name), str(tweet.created_at), str(getSubjectivity(cleaned_text)), str(getPolarity(cleaned_text))]) 
                print("Tweet Added")
```

## Call extract tweets function

```
for user in name_list: 
    extract_followers(user)
```

## Clean the tweets

```
df['Tweets'] = df['Tweets'].apply(cleanTxt)
```

## Show the cleaned tweets

```
print('df cleaned')
print (df)
```

## Create two new columns 'Subjectivity' & 'Polarity'

```
df['Subjectivity'] = df['Tweets'].apply(getSubjectivity)
df['Polarity'] = df['Tweets'].apply(getPolarity)
```

## Show the new dataframe with columns 'Subjectivity' & 'Polarity'

```
print ("df with subjectivity")
print (df)
```