# Is there a way to fetch twitter data whose dateCreated is above a given date?

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to fetch followers, friends and user_timeline whose date created is above 1st April.
Here is how I am fetching these three as of now

```
followers = tweepy.Cursor(self.api.followers, self.user_handle).items(max_limit)
followings = tweepy.Cursor(self.api.friends, self.user_handle).items(max_limit)
user_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(self.api.user_timeline, tweet_mode='extended').items(max_limit)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is a temporary work around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731259/tweepy-get-tweets-between-two-dates)

It is sorting out fetched items that meet the date requirements. Not ideal but close to a solution

For tweets, you can use the since_id param. By default, newer items have a greater id so specifying a since id as the greatest id from your previously fetched data will give you new results.
This may not be the case with followers and friends since I haven't seen the since_id param and followers don't have a follower_id field