# "Unexpected parameter: since" using tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm having a problem using tweepy for tweet scrape.

here's the code

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")

#armazenar os dados de login
log = pd.read_csv("tokens.csv")




#Criar objeto de autenticação
authenticate = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
#configurar o access token e o access secret
authenticate.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

#Criar o objeto da API
api = tweepy.API(authenticate, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#Coletar 2000 Tweets sobre Amazonia

search_term = "#Amazonia -filter:retweets"
#criar um cursor object
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=search_term, lang= "pt", since ="2018-01-01", until = "2021-12-01", tweet_mode="extended").items(2000)

#armazenar os tweets em uma variavel
all_tweets = [tweets for tweet in tweets]
```

I've got the following error when i run the code: "Unexpected parameter: since"

Any hints?

Comment: look at the document again. It doesn't seem to have an argument called since. Maybe another name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stack Overflow !

The `tweepy` client uses the api from Twitter. As Twitter updates its api, parameters may be removed. In this case, as noted [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), the API doesn't have a `since` parameter anymore.

I redirect you to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49731259), where another user tried the `since` parameter with another endpoint. The answers for this questions give good examples on how to filter results with time.