# Using tweepy: how to retrieve all tweets within past 5 minutes

Tags: python, json, tweepy

Im using tweepy to search for a keyword in all tweets in the last 5 minutes. But I couldn't find a way to do this. I saw the since_id and max_id arguments, but they only work if I know the tweet_id before 5 minutes.

Comment: "Every second, on average, around 6,000 tweets are tweeted on Twitter, which corresponds to over 350,000 tweets sent per minute…" according to http://www.internetlivestats.com/twitter-statistics/ Good luck trying to keep up with that.

Comment: @msw I'll be filtering them based on a specific keyword :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific `GET`feature that would allow that.

What you'll need to do is create a search for that keyword and `Get search/tweets` and use the since_id and max_id like you have and look at `time_created_at` from the JSON and filter yet again using that.

The problem with the previous step is that you're limited to 180 tweets /15 minutes. Another solution is to use the streaming API since it'll give you recent information most are within 5 minutes and you'll be able to filter by keywords as well.

Comment: I'm using the tweepy library to connect to streaming API. Are you sure that if I filter by keywords, I'll get all tweets in the last 5 mins, at least?

Comment: You'll get whatever twitter gives you... The streaming API is a free tool which encompasses about 1% of the all tweets. The 1% is not a solid number it's all done internally by twitter. If you need all the data... it'll cost you an arm and a leg.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is the following code possible?
`tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerms2, 
    since='2014-09-18 00:00:00', until='2014-09-18 18:44:00').items(999999999)`

Comment: With this , are we able to extract tweets from a specific time? I saw this piece of code elsewhere.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190946/specify-exact-time-to-start-and-end-the-collection-of-tweets-using-python-tweepy?lq=1

Comment: It won't work at all, his problem is not in the time formatting. He's inputting something into the search API that the API itself won't accept. You can't make up your own restrictions if they don't already exist [Search Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets). Nothing on there says about time specific information, therefore it's not possible. Like I said before,  you can only filter after you obtain your tweets.